# MQL4 Error: " '}' - not all control paths return a value"

Tags: mql4

Been doing this code in "Include" file. But I am encountering the error "not all control paths return a value. What should I do?

```
double CalculateTakeProfit (double entryPrice, int takeProfitPips, double GetPipValue)
   {
   if (bIsBuyPosition == True)
      {
      double result = 0;
      entryPrice = Ask;
      result = (entryPrice + takeProfitPips * GetPipValue());
      return result;
      }
   else if (bIsBuyPosition == False)
      {
      double result = 0;
      entryPrice = Bid;
      result = (entryPrice - takeProfitPips * GetPipValue());
      return result;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if... else` is wrong and you are also not using the variables passed to the function. You are instead referencing another function or overwriting them. Mixing variable types in a calculation can also lead to undesirable results (takeProfitPips should be of type `double`). You can also cut a few lines of your code down as follows

```
double CalculateTakeProfit(double entryPrice, double takeProfitPips, double GetPipValue)
{
   if(bIsBuyPosition) return(entryPrice+takeProfitPips*GetPipValue);
   else return(entryPrice-takeProfitPips*GetPipValue);
}
```